# Auto-complete with go-mode

Tags: emacs, go

I'm trying to enable auto-complete-mode whenever a .go file is loaded through go-mode. It works if I invoke auto-complete-mode manually for Go source files, but when I tried adding it to .emacs as below, it doesn't work:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook auto-complete-mode)
```

I've tried a few variations around it but none seem to work. Following is what the Go-Mode snippet currently looks like in my .emacs:

```
;; Load Go Mode
(require 'go-mode-load)
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
```

I tried creating my own hook function like this:

```
;; Load Go Mode
(require 'go-mode-load)
(defun auto-complete-for-go ()
  (auto-complete-mode 1))
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'auto-complete-for-go)
```

I also tried including the hook in `go-mode-load.el` and `go-mode.el`, as well as calling `auto-complete-mode` like this:

```
(auto-complete-mode t)
(provide 'go-mode)
```

Doesn't work either way. I also added the `go-mode-hook` to `auto-complete-default` function like so:

```
(defun ac-config-default ()
  (setq-default ac-sources '(ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
  ;; Other hooks
  (global-auto-complete-mode t))
```

That doesn't work either. What's the best way to trigger a command just after a major mode is enabled for a buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is workaround for now:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'go-mode)
```

I fixed the problem in v1.4 branch with the following commits.

- [Add go-mode to ac-modes](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/commit/c46d90fca2190349bc38dc4d30a6de0a753b43ca)
- [Add go-mode dictionary](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/commit/ecbd5fdbd5240471acca916348e84a8de862bcdc)

Comment: I applied the changes in github that you've linked to in my source list and it worked. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Which variations have you tried? It should work if you add a single-quote in front of `auto-complete-mode`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
```

Without this quote, `auto-complete-mode` is interpreted as a variable and the value of that variable is added to `go-mode-hook`. For this to make sense, such a variable should contain a function reference as its value. Most likely though there will be no variable named `auto-complete-mode` and Emacs will complain.

By adding a quote, you tell Emacs that this is not a variable, but the actual function you want the hook to call. See also [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html#Symbol-Type).

Comment: I've tried that as well. Following is what the Go-Mode snippet looks like in my .emacs:

    ;; Load Go Mode
    (require 'go-mode-load)
    (add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)

I also tried including the hook in go-mode-load.el and go-mode.el, as well as calling auto-complete-mode like this:

    (auto-complete-mode t)
    (provide 'go-mode)

Doesn't work either way. What's the best way to trigger a command just after a major mode is enabled for a buffer?

Comment: Oops! No formatting support in comments so I'm going to put the same text in my question above.